# Kotlin JavaScript Karma test fails

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Getting the following error when running the test

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```
js(IR) {
    useCommonJs()
    browser {
        testTask {
            useKarma {
                useChromeHeadless()
            }
        }
    }
    binaries.executable()
}
```

Increasing timeouts in `karma.config.d/karma.conf.js` didn't help:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        crossOriginAttribute: false,
        processKillTimeout: 90000,
        browserDisconnectTimeout: 90000,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 90000,
        frameworks: ['mocha'],
        client: {
            timeout: "9s",
            mocha: {
                timeout: "9s",
                reporter: "spec",
                args: ["timeout", "9s"]
            },
        }
    });
};
```

I can see that the config is merged into `build/js/packages/project-name-test/karma.conf.js` but looks like it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 2):

Use an integer instead of a string to specify Mocha's timeout:

```
config.set({
    client: {
        mocha: {
            timeout: 9000
        }
    }
})
```

It then worked for me for JsBrowser, but for JsNode I had to also set in `build.gradle(.kts)`:

```
kotlin {

    js(IR) {
        nodejs {
            testTask {
                useMocha {
                    timeout = "9s"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```